# Windows OS SSD transfer as secondary SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, operating-systems

I am about to say goodbye to my laptop and use a new one. But the SSD in the old one is fine and I wish to transfer it to my new one to replace the HDD in the new laptop with the SSD from the oldie.

Now the SSD is a bootable system SSD, so my oldie runs Windows from it. I don't want to use it as a Windows drive in my new laptop, but as a secondary drive to the existing SSD in the new laptop.

Is there a way to remove Windows / remove the bootable parts of an SSD without removing the programs/executables, documents and other user-specific folders on it? So how to remove Windows, but nothing else, just to make it a slave so to say?

I have googled around, but I'm being flooded with answers and videos about how to [physically install a SATA drive](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-sata-hard-disk-slave-56859.html) or [how to slave a HDD](https://dtidatarecovery.com/how-to-slave-hard-drive/), so I'm stuck.

Comment: I think that it would be easier / quicker to: 1) Back up contents via windows to another drive 2) Format drive 3) Put contents back on.

Comment: @EricF Thanks for your comment. It crossed my mind for sure. The issue is I did that before, just to find out later that some important folders were tucked away in the windows directory or other obscure places, resulting in lost SQL-based databases and so forth. Pretty bad. I'm really not so keen to go that way again...

Comment: Those important folders shouldn't be under Windows anyway. That's a system folder for the OS and software only.

Comment: @AliceD If you had a method to do what you desire of removing windows items, chances are great those same folders would go away. As Gabriela stated those are system folders so you shouldn't have other items there. Either way the end result of my way vs what you suggest is the same